# How to simplify the writing of a conditional test after a test to know if the element exists?

Tags: php, algorithm

I frequently encounter a recurring problem in writing my javascript n codes.
I need to test for the presence of an element and then test if it has a value. I think it is possible to write this code more simply.

My problem is that i need to do the same action 2 if the item doesn't exist and it doesn't have the value i expect.

```
if(isset($_POST['test'])
{
    if($_POST['test]==$value)
      ... action1 ...
    else 
      ... action2 ...
}
else ... action2 ...
```

Comment: PHP implements short circuit evaluation. So `if (isset && ==value) action1 else action2`

Comment: thanks @Yves Daoust, this implement exist in all version of php?
i'm a newbie in stackoverflow, if your comment is the solution, when i share this?

Comment: I confirm this behavior already in PHP4, and I would be surprised that it was different before.

Comment: thanks, it's for php 7 and 8 site.
Perfect and simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

Thank at the comment [Yves Daoust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1196549/yves-daoust):

> PHP implements short circuit evaluation. So if (isset && ==value) action1 else action2

I have write a complete code for share this solution

```
<?php
$action1='action1';
$action2='action2';
$test=null;
if (isset($test) %26%26 $test=='test')
 echo $action1;
else
 echo $action2;
```

[phpfiddle example](https://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn$action1=%27action1%27;%5Cn$action2=%27action2%27;%5Cn$test=null;%5Cnif%20(isset($test)%20%2526%2526%20$test==%27test%27)%5Cn%20echo%20$action1;%5Cnelse%5Cn%20echo%20$action2;)